# Which rest http method is suitable for migrating user details from one DB to another?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, microservices

I have to expose a rest end point which moves the user data from mongoDB to a SQLDB. No input is taken from the consumer of this api, also no output is shown to the consumer. Just an OK response is to be sent on successful completion. Consumer will invoke the api whenever needed and only work of the api is to fetch any user details from mongoDB and if found move to SQLDB.
I am a bit confused which http method should be used. As per my analysis , method should be idempotent.
I am confused between PUT and GET.

Answer (score 1):

None of them.

Your API should be hiding the database backend from the clients of the API. The movement of data to a different  database should be done invisibly and automatically without the user of the API having to explicitly request the movement.

Comment: Correct , but the thing is , i need to expose the api to other applications. So the consumer here would be just a different module of my bigger software.

Answer (score 0):

From microsoft REST End Point best practices

> PUT either creates or replaces the resource at the specified URI. The
>   body of the request message specifies the resource to be created or
>   updated.

So, you should be using **PUT** for moving resource data, as described here

> A PUT request creates a resource or updates an existing resource. The
>   client specifies the URI for the resource. The request body contains a
>   complete representation of the resource. If a resource with this URI
>   already exists, it is replaced. Otherwise a new resource is created,
>   if the server supports doing so. PUT requests are most frequently
>   applied to resources that are individual items, such as a specific
>   customer, rather than collections. A server might support updates but
>   not creation via PUT. Whether to support creation via PUT depends on
>   whether the client can meaningfully assign a URI to a resource before
>   it exists. If not, then use POST to create resources and PUT or PATCH
>   to update.

This is also used by amazon web services(AWS) 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingREST.html

```
PUT /bucket HTTP/1.1
Host: atlantic.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-copy-source: /pacific/flotsam
```